# Problem using xargs to send commands to a screen from within a bash script

Tags: bash, ubuntu, xargs, mplayer

I'm currently writing a simple bash script for recording a streaming radio stream. The logistics of getting into work and getting set up mean that I miss about 30 minutes of my favourite breakfast show, so I'm writing this script with the intention of putting it on a cron schedule on my work machine to start recording about 15 minutes before I get to work.

The following excerpt from the script does not work:

`echo ${FILEFULLPATH} | xargs -t screen -dmS ${STATION_NAME}Stream mplayer ${STATION_URL} -dumpstream -dumpfile`

However, running the `xargs -t` output works perfectly - `screen -ls` shows the screen and `screen -r` shows that the command is indeed running. This is that output command:

`screen -dmS RadioXStream mplayer http://radiostream.net/ -dumpstream -dumpfile ~/radio/radiostream_06102015-1316.mp3`

I've used `set -x` and everything looks fine. When I run `screen -ls` after running the script, the screen that is supposed to have created does not exist.

*I based this command on an earlier script I wrote for a Minecraft server, with the only main difference being that I use xargs here for the filepath, as it was wrapping a relative directory in quotes, e.g `'~/radio/file.mp3'`*

Comment: I think you're overcomplicating your script by using `xargs` and `screen`. Why not simply have cron run `mplayer http://radiostream.net/ -dumpstream -dumpfile ~/radio/radiostream_06102015-1316.mp3`?

Comment: ... with `radiostream_06102015-1316.mp3` generate by `$(date "+radiostream_%d%m%Y_%H%M.mp3")` in command line

Comment: Because I do this: `FILEFULLPATH="${DIRECTORY}${STATION_NAME}_${DATETAG}.mp3"`

Answer (score 0):

The problem must have been caused by using xargs. I solved my problem by sticking all the variables on the command line instead of putting them in a variable:

`screen -dmS ${STATION_NAME}Stream mplayer ${STATION_URL} -dumpstream -dumpfile ${DIRECTORY}${STATION_NAME}_${DATETAG}.mp3`

Thanks for the comments.